# iOS:How to change color of the separator in UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a small project with a `UISplitViewController`.
The `masterView` is a `tableView` and the `detailView` is a `collectionView`. The background colors of them are both black color. But when the project runs in simulator, there is a separator between `tableView` and `collectionView`, which has a white color. I want to change the separator's color but I can't find anything helpful in the `UISplitViewController` Class reference.

Does someone know how to change the separator's color?

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of the color you are taking about?

Comment: It might be your window, or the view controller's view, or the split view controller's view. Use View Debugging to find out what it is, and then color it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change the background color of the `UISplitViewController`

```
yourSplitViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used to think that a SplitViewController only contains a masterView and a detailView.Now I realize that  it has its own view.

Comment: This works when I have the `UISplitViewController` in Landscape orientation. When I flip to Portrait it returns to original separator color. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Yes, does not seem to work for portrait mode, only for landscape.