# How to change the divider colour of a split navigation view in SwiftUI for macOS Catalyst?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making an app in swiftUI that uses Mac Catalyst to run on macOS. I have added a navigation view and it works well on iOS. When I run the app on macOS, it shows as a split view, which is great, but it has a dividing line between the detail view and the list view. This isn't a problem, but the line is an off-grey colour that doesn't match the rest of my colour scheme.

How can I change the colour of the dividing line in a split view using SwiftUI? Is there a modifier I can use or does it require changing the appearance of the split view somehow?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did you try `.border(Color.red)`

Comment: Yes, no luck I'm afraid, adding the border colour to the navigation view surrounded the combined detail and list view with a red border, leaving the grey divider as is. Adding the border colour to the contained views just surrounded those views, the divider remained the same.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use `UIViewRepresentable` and interface with UIKit to use `UISplitViewController`. You can then following this answer to change the color of your separator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685411/ioshow-to-change-color-of-the-separator-in-uisplitviewcontroller

Comment: It’s 2022. Is there a way to solve this?